# Change international settings during iOS automation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'd like to have my iOS automation be able to set the devices language before running a specific test. Has anyone solved this problem?

I really wish the iOS automation framework allowed me to hit the home button, click settings, etc., but that's not currently supported... I already use a fiddler service I built to fake dropped connections, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this by changing the preference files for the Simulator in my Screen Shooter utility.

https://github.com/jonathanpenn/ui-screen-shooter

That sample project uses UI Automation and shell scripts to take screen shots in different languages. Check out the `bin/choose_sim_language` script for more details.

Comment: Interesting. Before I dive in, could this be modified to work with a real device?

Comment: This tool is great. I wish the simulator was an actual emulator, but life isn't always fair. I'm also pretty impressed with your blog, I'll be reading it frequently. I work as a Test Engineer on a very large iOS project, so I deal with the bleeding edge of iOS Automation every day. Enjoy your upvote!

Answer (score 0):

You can set your language and locale for each test class in `setUP`.
Something like this:

```
override func setUp() {
    app.launchArguments += ["-AppleLanguages", "(\(en-US))"]
    app.launchArguments += ["-AppleLocale", "\"\(en-US)\""]
    app.launch()
}
```

List of language codes can be found here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html